# Why is $M$ faithful as an $A/{\alpha}$ module?

Tags: commutative-algebra

I have some confusion on Atiyah Commutative algebra

On Page No $20$  it is written that

> An $A-$Module is faithful if $Ann(M)=0$.If $Ann(M)=\alpha$ ,then $M$  is faithful as  an $A/{\alpha}$ module

**My confusion** : Why is $M$   faithful as  an $A/{\alpha}$ module ?

**My thinking** : $Ann_{A/{\alpha}}(M)=\{r+\alpha | r \in A \ \text{and} \ rM={0}\}=\{ r+\alpha |r \in Ann(M)\}$

$\implies Ann_{A/{\alpha}}(M) = \frac{Ann(M)}{\alpha}=\frac{\alpha}{\alpha}=\frac{0}{0} \neq 0$

Therefore  $M$  is **not** faithful as  an $A/{\alpha}$ module

Comment: What you write is correct up to the point $\alpha/\alpha$. This is simply the zero module. I cannot tell where your thinking is going wrong at the end exactly. Not sure if it's just notation, but I advise you to recall that quotients of modules are not literal fractions.

Comment: @Thorgott  I thought that $0/0 $ undefine

Comment: If $0$ means the natural number $0$, then the fraction $0/0$ is undefined. If $0$ means the trivial abelian group, then the quotient $0/0$ is defined and just $0$ again. You have to always keep in mind what the notation you use actually means. Also, while $\alpha/\alpha=0/0$ is accurate, it would probably help if you indicate how you arrive at this step. "Cancelling" quotients does not work quite the same way as cancelling fractions.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The action of $A/\alpha$ on $M$ is given by $(r+\alpha)x=rx$ for $x \in M$. If $(r+\alpha)M=rM=0$, then by assumption $r \in \alpha$ so $r+\alpha=\alpha$ which is $0$ in $A/\alpha$.